# How to execute Script functions with more params - Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I try execute Script with functions who have more params and every try returns Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: ReferenceError: coords is not defined
```

my script :

```
enter code here

if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)

.executeScript("setNewCellType(new ZmianaTypuCommandFactory(),currentRozdzial,currentTable,this.activeCoords)");
```

I find functions in developers tools and his form is :

```
 function setNewCellType(factory,nrRozdzial,tab,coords,newState,mode)
```

and I set break point in this place to get the parameters, and parameters is :

```
setNewCellType(newZmianaTypuCommandFactory(),currentRozdzial,currentTable,this.activeCoords,params);

this.activeCoords have value 
(col: 2
colspan: 1
row: 2
rowspan: 1
siatkaCol: 2
siatkaRow: 2)
```

someone can help me ?

the element I want to use has a dynamic value in this session these items are more.

More scripts :

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("addTableRowCount")).clear();
 driver.findElement(By.id("addTableRowCount")).sendKeys("9");
 driver.findElement(By.id("addTableColCount")).clear();
 driver.findElement(By.id("addTableColCount")).sendKeys("2");
 driver.findElement(By.id("addTableOK")).click();
 driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
 driver.findElement(By.id("tytulTabeli")).sendKeys("Tytuł tabeli - 1");
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//p[text()='Obszar danych']")));
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text()='Obszar danych']")).click();   
    if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
        .executeScript("setNewCellType(new ZmianaTypuCommandFactory(),currentRozdzial,currentTable,this.activeCoords)");
```

@Zhivko.Kostadinov

```
var ZmianaTypuCommandFactory = Class.create(CellTypeChangeCommandFactory,{
initialize:  function($super){
$super(new ZmianaTypuValidator());
this.wymagalnoscFactory = new WymagalnoscCommandFactory();
},
createSingleCmd:    function(nrRozdzial,tab,coords,newState){
if(newState.cellType.cellTypeInt == TYPY_KOMOREK.ZAZNACZENIE.cellTypeInt)
{ var cmd = new CompositeCommand();
var typeCmd = new ZmianaTypuCommand();
typeCmd.setState(tab,coords,newState);
cmd.addCommand(typeCmd);
var wymagalnoscCmd = this.wymagalnoscFactory.createCmd(nrRozdzial,tab,coords,true);
if(wymagalnoscCmd){
 cmd.addCommand(wymagalnoscCmd);
return cmd;
}
else{
return typeCmd;}}
else{
var cmd = new ZmianaTypuCommand();
cmd.setState(tab,coords,newState);
return cmd; }}});
```

Comment: Pls, add code for newZmianaTypuCommandFactory().

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your issue is here:

```
this.activeCoords
```

you've got to remember that "this" pointer depends on the context. You have to pass "absolute references", i.e. something that you can reference from the console, as script executor, afaik runs in the global context.

A good verification approach for test scripts - if you can run it in the dev tools console, you should be able to run it with scriptExecutor

If data is always the same during the test, you can do:

```
executeScript("setNewCellType(new ZmianaTypuCommandFactory(),currentRozdzial,currentTable,
{
    col: 2
    colspan: 1
    row: 2
    rowspan: 1
    siatkaCol: 2
    siatkaRow: 2 
},
{
   // params data in here
   cellType: {type:'Kw'}
}
)");
```

Comment: This solution is correct. But I still want to change cellType cellType: {…}
​​
cellTypeInt: 1
​​
guiType: "LG_Kw"
​​
label: "kwota"
​​
type: "Kw"
​​
__proto__: Object { … }
​
dictId: null      Can You help me with this params ? cellType is params in function  setNewCellType(new ZmianaTypuCommandFactory(),currentRozdzial,currentTable,this.activeCoords,params);

Comment: @user9792362 you can add another structure for params, according to the method signature. See the edited code.

Comment: you think this solutions will bee ok ? : if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
   
  
  .executeScript("setNewCellType(new ZmianaTypuCommandFactory(),currentRozdzial,currentTable,{col: 2, colspan: 1, row: 2,rowspan: 1, siatkaCol: 1,siatkaRow: 2,cellType: {type:'Kw'} })");

Comment: @user9792362 a bit differently. you have put the cellType to the coords object, but it has to be a separate object that you pass as params. I've edited the code.